# "Apply Rules" to Sent Mail folder in OS X 10.9 Mavericks does not work

Tags: mail.app, macos

Any idea why in Mail 7.0 (part of OS X 10.9 Mavericks,) when I select a group of messages in the Sent Mail folder and do Message --> Apply Rules command, nothing happens?

(In prior versions of OS X back to 10.5, my extensive list of 70+ rules automatically moved messages from my Sent folder to various other sorted folders. I have several plain POP3 accounts set up in Mail.app, not leaving messages on the server.)

Comment: Could you share a screenshot?

Comment: Nevermind -- I dumped Apple Mail years ago & switched to "Mailmate.app". Not as well-integrated as Mail.app but far, far more reliable.

Answer (score 1):

Try selecting all messages within your group folder instead, than Apply Rules command.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but you may be able to get this functionality from Mail Act-On (now in beta for Mavericks).

http://www.indev.ca/MailActOn.html